# Directory of ssh accidentally deleted

Tags: macos

I'm working with OSX, the lastest version. I have accidentally deleted these directories:

1. `/private/etc/ssh`
2. `/etc/ssh`

How can I recover these folders so I can use SSH?   The last solution is to reinstall the OS, but I want avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `/private/etc/ssh` and `/etc/ssh` are the same folder (`/etc` is a symbolic link to `/private/etc`).

I believe you only need to restore the configuration files `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` and the keys will be automatically regenerated. You could copy these from another Mac, or create your own based on the documentation provided in `man sshd_config` and `man ssh_config`.

Another option could be installing a separate copy of OpenSSH using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then copying over the relevant files. To do so, install Homebrew according to the instructions on its homepage, then install OpenSSH with this command:

```
brew install openssh
```

Once it's installed, you can replace the missing system files with those installed by Homebrew:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/etc/ssh/* /private/etc/ssh/
sudo cp /usr/local/etc/ssh/* /etc/ssh/
```

You'll have to then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to remove all the `/usr/local` prefixes in front of the paths of the keys and such. If you don't edit the file, but keep Homebrew's OpenSSH installed, it will probably still work.